# Python SessionNotCreatedException using Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using this code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

`import chromedriver_binary`  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

here is the installation I did

[image]

However, I am getting an error

> SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of
>   ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84

It looks like in the command prompt it should be supported? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That means your chrome browser is outdated. Remember one thing, the chromedriver version MUST be same as the chrome browser version. Please verify the same.